# Windows forms app which uses System.IO.Ports is crashing after some time

Tags: c#, winforms, serial-port, modbus-tcp

I have a C# WinForms application that uses EasyModbus library to pool data from several slaves on RS485 RTU.
Application crashes in about 40 minutes of running.
It crashes in System.IO.Ports .dll.

This is what I get:

> System.NullReferenceException
> HResult=0x80004003
> Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
> Source=System.IO.Ports
> StackTrace:
> at System.IO.Ports.SerialStream.EventLoopRunner.CallReceiveEvents(Object state)
> at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallbackDefaultContext.Execute()
> at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
> at System.Threading.PortableThreadPool.WorkerThread.WorkerThreadStart()
> at System.Threading.Thread.StartCallback()

Here are methods which I use to read and write to modbus(serial port):

```
public int[]? ReadMultipleRegisters(byte nodeID, int startAddress, int quantity)
        {
            int[] res=null;
            int repeat = 0;
            _mut.WaitOne();
        repeat:
            repeat++;
            try
            {
                _modbusClient.UnitIdentifier = nodeID;
                res = _modbusClient.ReadHoldingRegisters(startAddress, quantity);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.Write("Error during Reading multiple registers, repeat:"+repeat+" nodeID:"+nodeID+" stAdr:"+startAddress+" quantity:"+ quantity);
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                if (repeat != _repeats)
                {
                    goto repeat;
                }
                if(repeat==_repeats)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("!#!#!#!#!#READING FAILED!#!#!##!#!#!##!");
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                _mut.ReleaseMutex();
            }
            if(repeat>1)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(repeat+"MORE THAN ONE REPEAT!!!!!!!!!!!");
            }
            return res;
        }
public void WriteSingleRegister(byte id, int address, int value) {
            try
            {
                _mut.WaitOne();
                _modbusClient.UnitIdentifier = id;
                _modbusClient.WriteSingleRegister(address, value);
            }
            catch (Exception ex) 
            {
                //todo ob napaki
                Debug.Write("Error during Writing to single register, ");
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
            finally { 
                _mut.ReleaseMutex();
            }

        }
```

I don't know how what I am doing wrong and how to catch this exception.
If anyone could help I will be very thankful.
Thanks.

Comment: Hard to say, as your stack trace doesn't match anything in your code. Might be EasyModBus itself, are you on the latest version?

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Charlieface. Yes, it looks like it crashing outside my code....
Yes I am using the latest version, 5.6.0 of EasyModbus.
Ill try to use some other modbus library to see if the problem is in EasyModbus.

Comment: Just switch to NModbus library and it is working fine without crashing.